# What’s the difference between a plano-convex lens and a convex-plano?

Tags: optics, geometric-optics, lenses

I guess they’re essentially the same but one (plano-convex) has the plane surface to the incoming ray and then the convex or spherical surface while the convex-plano have the spherical surface to the incoming rays and the then the plane surface. Is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

A plano-convex lens and a convex-plano lens can have different aberration properties.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is correct.

plano-convex: plane side + spherical side

convex-plano: spherical side + plane side

@robphy's remarks are correct as well. This is apparent by considering a incoming collimated on-axis beam being focused by the lens. If the plane side is in front all ray bending must occur on the second surface, resulting in large incidence angles and therefore a larger violation of paraxial optics compared to the convex-plano case where ray bending is split between both surfaces -> stronger aberrations